# Folder Structure for Nodejs Multi Subdomain site

Tags: node.js, nginx

So i am building a website using NodeJS where i will use Nginx as a reverse proxy to my app/apps. I will be using jade and sharing some layouts between subdomain and displaying specific content according to subdomain. I am trying to figure out from alot of research the best method of structuring the app. Is the best way to run each subdomain as a separate app on the same server? Or can i link them as one app? Please share your ideas and suggestions so i can make a decision and begin my coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue with using the same domain across multiple apps is security in regards to cookies.  If apps are independent, then you might want to ensure a vulnerability in one app would not necessarily affect your other apps.

Otherwise, with nginx, there is really no limitation on your setup, however you decide to go.  You can use nginx to easily join or disjoin multiple domains and/or ports/servers, into whatever setup you wish.

Whether you decide to go with multiple domains or multiple paths on a single domain have more to do with what kinds of apps you have in mind, and how logically separate would they appear to be from one another.  With the help of the [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite) directive, even if you make a "wrong" choice initially, if you do have a desire, you could always fix it later on (preserving all existing links flawlessly), pretty much without any ill effect.

Comment: so would it be better in terms of app load to separate each subdomain into a separate app then join them to run together? Just trying to think how much overload i would get just having it as one app as well as how i would manage otherwise update all apps easily.

Comment: @Elevant, nginx is highly efficient, and is unlikely to be the slowing-down factor, regardless of which way you go; separate domains generally do make things more independent and easier to manage, but it all depends!

Comment: Thanks mate ill give it a try but might have to chane stricture as the app grows ty

Comment: @Elevant, sure, thanks for accept!  BTW, if you want to take a look at some extreme remapping of a domain to multiple distinct services / apps, take a look at http://mdoc.su/, it's entirely open-source!

Answer (score 1):

I am running multiple web applications (totally separated in different folders and running on different ports) on server with nxinx as proxy for different subdomains. However, if you want to make more subdomains for one application, the best way should be to structure it by URL.

For example you have `mysite.com/books` but you want `books.mysite.com` to be go to domain for books. You make proxy in nginx configs to redirect traffic from `mysite.com/books` to `books.mysite.com`.